# Leaflet map drawn upper dropdown semantic-ui

Tags: leaflet, semantic-ui

I'm drawing a map with leaflet. I have a semantic-ui dropdown menu.
The map is going over the dropdown menu.
Is it possible to draw the map on background ?

[image]

Comment: Fix z-index via CSS. Higher number goes on top of lower number. Menu should have higher z-index than map

Comment: well, so easy ;) thanks.